# Multiple services on same url in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

What happens if you have two services in kubernestes that exposes the same url in their ingress configuration?

Comment: What ingress controller are you using? This will be implementation specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ingress definitions with the same `ingress` annotation and `host` should be merged into a single virtualhost.

The details of how this is done and how `path` collisions are handled is implementation specific for each ingress controller.

For example, [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) [sorts the ingress definitions by `CreationTimestamp`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/e568fba8c921abc48554d34e53a58732839be269/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go#L747) to keep the oldest definitions in place.